# Php, smarty autolink modifier, prevent modifying text with dots into links

Tags: php, hyperlink, smarty, smarty3

I'm using smarty for my website and special link modifier that turns into clickable links text from users comments. It works perfect except it is turning such pieces of text as `p.s.` `someword.asag` and so on? Is there any way to improve it and prevent such things to happen, keeping it work only on real web links?

```
function smarty_modifier_autolink($string)
{
    $string = preg_replace_callback('#(?:https?://\S+)|(?:www.\S+)|(?:\S+\.\S+)#', function($arr)
    {
        $email = filter_var($arr[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === $arr[0] ? true : false;
        $origArr0 = $arr[0];
        if(strpos($arr[0], 'http://') !== 0 && strpos($arr[0], 'https://') !== 0)
        {
            $arr[0] = 'http://' . $arr[0];
        }
        $url = parse_url($arr[0]);
        // images
        if(isset($url['path'])){
            if(preg_match('#\.(png|jpg|gif)$#', $url['path']))
            {
                return '<img class="img-responsive" src="'. $arr[0] . '" />';
            }
        }
        // youtube
        if(in_array($url['host'], array('www.youtube.com', 'youtube.com'))
          && $url['path'] == '/watch'
          && isset($url['query']))
        {
            parse_str($url['query'], $query);
            return sprintf('<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/%s" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>', $query['v']);
        }
        //links
        if($email){
            return sprintf('<a href="mailto:%1$s">%1$s</a>', $origArr0);
        }else{
            return sprintf('<a href="%1$s" target="_blank">%2$s</a>', $arr[0], str_replace($url['scheme'].'://', '', $arr[0]));
        }
    }, $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: maybe you need somekind of a list with domain endings you want to replace an then build a different regex...

Comment: Yeah, this is what I actually decided to do